# referencing el-date-picker inner elements

Tags: vuejs3, element-plus, vue-options-api, el-date-picker

```
 <ElDatePicker ref="datePickerRef" />


 mounted() {
  console.log(this.$refs.datePickerRef.$el.querySelector('.el-input__inner');
 }
```

How do I convert this to vue3 options api? Tried ways suggested by chatgpt already, but nothing worked

Answer (score 1):

You mean in composition API I suppose, because you are already in options API, here it is supposing you are on typescript :

```
<script setup lang="ts">
  import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue';
  import { ElDatePicker } from './your/path/to/component.vue';

  const datePickerRef = ref<typeof ElDatePicker | null>(null);

  onMounted(() => {
    if (datePickerRef.value) {
        console.log(datePickerRef.value.$el.querySelector('.el-input__inner'));
    }
  });
</script>

<template>
  <ElDatePicker ref="datePickerRef" />
</template>
```

if you are not in typescript:

```
<script setup>
  import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue';

  const datePickerRef = ref(null);

  onMounted(() => {
    if (datePickerRef.value) {
        console.log(datePickerRef.value.$el.querySelector('.el-input__inner'));
    }
  });
</script>

<template>
  <ElDatePicker ref="datePickerRef" />
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from "vue";

const myReference = ref(null);

onMounted(() => {
  console.log(myReference.value); <-- This will output a DOM node
})
</script>

<template>
  <h1 ref="myReference">I have access to the DOM reference now</h1>
</template>
```

Here is an example of using $refs in Vue 3 with Composition API and Script Setup
[view more](https://zelig880.com/how-to-use-refs-in-vue-3-with-composition-api-and-script-setup)